# Change default / base language for t()

Tags: i18n-l10n

Currently when I use t() it shows me originaltext in english and i can translate into french and german. But I want to change the default language to french so when I write t('Salut') I will translate it into english, german, etc. later. But how/where can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the language configuration page here

admin/config/regional/language

And set the default language to French.

Comment: It is already. It still thinks it is english and i can translate into french.